# Where can one find the total number of unique users in the entire Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, statistics

I've looked on the [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and I can't seem to find the number of unique users on the entire stack exchange system.  It maybe that these numbers don't exist, but it seems like you just have to count the number of **valid unique open-ids** across every stack exchange site and you have it.  Maybe I'm being silly and these numbers are easy to find.

Can anyone help me to find a query or statistic page that gives me this info?

Edit, simplification: Where can I find the closest count of the **total number of people on planet earth who have a single stack exchange account**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 4598280

<sup>as per 25 Jan 2015</sup>

I [put together this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/268584/distinct-stack-wide-accounts) which selects and counts the distinct user AccountId (which is the Stack Exchange network account).

Thus, there are 4.6 million distinct stack exchange accounts

Because the SEDE data is only updated once a week (typically Sunday mornings UTC), the data will always be up to a week stale, but that should be good enough for engineering purposes....

Comment: Almost 10M as of today.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy to do with the API:

1. Retrieve a list of all the sites with StackAuth: `http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites`
2. For each of the sites (with state == 'normal'), call:

   `http://api.`**`site-domain`**`/1.0/stats`

   ...and extract the `total_users` field.
3. Then add up the user numbers.

Comment: Will this method prevent users that have accounts on different stack exchange sites under the same openId from being counted multiple times?  Or is it simply counting the number of users on each site and adding them together?

Comment: @Mark: the latter. As for unique users, you *may* be able to use this tool: http://stackusers.com/ (But I don't really know.) From the tools there, it looks like '402086'.

Comment: A month later the number is 402116, so that can't be accurate, since I sincerely doubt that the stack exchange system only added 30 users in one month.

Answer (score 4):

It is listed here now, on the sidebar:

https://stackexchange.com/sites

> #### Network Stats
>
> - 46 Q&A sites
> - 809,534 users
> - 1.7 million questions
> - 4 million answers
> - 2 million visits per day

Comment: This information is not anymore given. Actually, with the new theme, I don't see any sidebar.

Comment: @kia it is on the homepage http://stackexchange.com/ right now it says "82 Q&A sites, 1.8 million users, 3.7 million questions, 7.6 million answers"

Comment: This is no longer relevant. The stat moved to the [About page](http://stackexchange.com/about), but it's showing only Stack Overflow users, not overall network users.

Comment: Click on the menu button on [http://stackexchange.com/](stackexchange.com) and you will see the stats [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic). But I would like to know how to display the number of "active" users for each site. Thanks.

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't appear to lead to network stats anymore, I can't recall where they are to correct the link.