# Difference between total number of users in the live sites and the API

Tags: support, api

A large portion of users are not listed in the users page. For example by roughly calculating the number of users on super user using formula `#perpage * #pages` one gets 103K users. However looking at the field total_`users` on http://api.superuser.com/1.0/stats shows 130K users. That's a 20% difference. on stackoverflow the numbers are 1,223K and 1,504K with a 19% difference. So the question is what is the criteria for the excluded users and why are they excluded.

**Related Questions**

- [Where do you view the total number of users on Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47836/201088)
- [Where can one find the total number of unique users in the entire Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77973/201088)

Comment: My guess is that great many users get "purged" for various reasons from the live database (spammers, merging of accounts, manual deletion etc) while the offline database still keeps all of them.

Comment: that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unregistered users aren't listed in users page, according to [How many users does Stack Overflow actually have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109573/how-many-users-does-stack-overflow-actually-have).

The ~300k difference for SO matches up with the (one year old) figures in Nick's answer if you take into account the fact that registration became mandatory to ask questions about that time too, so the number of unregistered users probably stabilized.